# How to allow custom tags in tinyMce editor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tinymce, tinymce-5

```
      <textarea><div style="margin-top: 15px;">           <div class="dropdown "> <p> hello my name is <Enter Your Name> </p>             <p>  hehe</p>           </div>      </div>    </textarea>
```

I'm expecting the output will show in text editor like:  **hello my name is <Enter Your Name> **  Inside the tinyMce Editor I want to allow the angle brackets only for non html tags.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

usually you have to escape special characters.
in your case you should be able to achieve it like this:
`&lt;Enter Your Name&gt;`

Comment: yeah but it'll print the other tags to the editor.

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, you need to be more specific.
here it looks like it works: https://codepen.io/eliakocher/pen/qBKbmBM

Comment: Thanks for the response.

But I want to achieve here that I just want to print the invalid tags only if I used the example you mentioned above it will priint the other tags to the tinyMCE editor because my data is coming from the backend I'm not using the static data.

Comment: ok maybe create a new question and provide a good example with the actual code.